# VisualBoy Advance game colour problem - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-center, emulation

I just downloaded VisualBoy Advance from the Ubuntu Software Center for the first time to play a ROM, to be specific Pokemon FireRed, which i downloaded from coolroms. When I run the ROM I see the wrong colors showing up, the ROM runs fine though. I've played the game loads of times before and am sure it's not like this and NO I cannot ignore it and continue playing as it ruins the game as well as my mood to play it. I searched for a while over the net and found [THIS](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1720523) it has the exact problem I am experiencing but that doesn't solve it as he shifted his Ubuntu version and got it to work, but I want to stick to mine (12.04) so any help?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't find how to solve the problem, but tried a different emulator. To be specific VBA-M/VBAM and it working great with the ROM.